# ESlint error, Type '() => Promise<void>' is missing the following properties from type 'Promise<void>': then, catch, [Symbol.toStringTag], finally

Tags: javascript, typescript, eslint, typescript-eslint

I'm getting an error that I can only fix with adding `any` as the return value.

```
export const dbConnections: any = {};

export const connectDb: Promise<void> = async () => {
    if (dbConnections.isConnected) {
        return;
    }

    try {
        const db = await mongoose.connect(config.get('mongoURI'), {
            useNewUrlParser: true,
            useUnifiedTopology: true,
            useFindAndModify: false,
            useCreateIndex: true,
        });

        dbConnections.isConnected = db.connections[0].readyState;
    } catch (err) {
        createError('Error caught connecting to db!', err);
    }
};
```

This throws an error,

```
export const connectDb: Promise<void> = async () => {
                                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Type '() => Promise<void>' is missing the following properties
  from type 'Promise<void>': then, catch, [Symbol.toStringTag], finally
```

If I do `any` instead of `Promise<void>`, then the error disappears, but that's obviously not how I'm trying to go about this. How can I fix this lint error?

Comment: Because you're assigning a *function* to `connectDb` not a promise. Either you need the type to be `() => Promise<void>` or change it so the value is the executed function (perhaps by using an IIFE).

Comment: Also, it's not a lint error - it's a *compiler error*. TS is doing its job correctly by alerting you that what you *want to have* as `connectDb` and what you *actually have* for `connectDb` doesn't match.

Comment: Setting it to `export const connectDb = async (): Promise<void> => {` worked, thank you. I just want to note, that this is an existing project with TS, and only an hour ago I decided to add ESLint to it following [this](https://khalilstemmler.com/blogs/typescript/eslint-for-typescript/) tutorial, and that's when I started getting this error. Thanks again

Comment: I'm getting this error when I try the code in the [Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwgOwM7wCYCMDCLnAIwCWKqAXHAIbICecAvHAN4C+A3AFCeiSyJl4SZASIARLJQAKUCAFtiqYAB4AbhGIYAfI2qpayBHAAUASkY7mnODbjEAZiex4RhEmQB0il6JjAM5la2wXBQwDAArlDIXMGs3MEwUPRBITbC6HDYulQA7lTE8HIoAOYQEEoewr7GwvbEJR4l4cYA5MXIZQCqAEoAkq2mADQs1mkhEUoAcsC5XVAANlJUUEpQlEkRwENj47aTwF3IDsT+ACoQkAsQJbQbUFs7e8EHAGLEyBgAgp8AshAYBx3OD2KgLJRPZ42A44MJUPx9T6ge6PXYhVimLho4LOfBuUhoLyoHxufy6bBVPFEAmoADaAAYALoeOEYWgAZRg8OAsVsrEQ8IQAAsTMAoFBAtjbAg4X4AKLi6BtBWyKACiIlIVCKkkTpwGAQLJYACErRGYolvJs8Q4QA)

Answer (score 3):

Issue is in function declaration. You need to give the return type as `Promise<void>`.

```
export const connectDb = async (): Promise<void> => {
    if (dbConnections.isConnected) {
        return;
    }

    try {
        const db = await mongoose.connect(config.get('mongoURI'), {
            useNewUrlParser: true,
            useUnifiedTopology: true,
            useFindAndModify: false,
            useCreateIndex: true,
        });

        dbConnections.isConnected = db.connections[0].readyState;
    } catch (err) {
        createError('Error caught connecting to db!', err);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Asynchronous functions in typescript return promise value.

like this:

```js
export const dbConnections: any = {};

export const connectDb: () => Promise<void> = async () => {
    ...
};
```